# ymax and ymin values (in error-bar) does not appear in geompoint

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I am trying to plot a chart with the mean, maximum and minimum value of 4 variables (amount, exploration, size, source), but the lines referring to ymax and ymin (error-bar) do not appear.
These 4 variable are  repeated because it appear for marine and freshwater data.

I also would like to invert the graph axes by placing the variables names in the column est on the y axis and the mean values on the x axis.

Does anyone know the error of my script?

```js
Dataset<-read.csv(file= "ICglm.csv", header= TRUE, sep= ";" )
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(Dataset,aes(x=est,ymin=min, ymax=max, y=mean, shape=est))
#Added horizontal line at y=0, error bars to points and points with size two
p <- p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=min, ymax=max), width=0, color="black") + 
  geom_point(aes(size=1)) 
#Removed legends and with scale_shape_manual point shapes set to 1 and 16
p <- p + guides(size=FALSE,shape=FALSE) + scale_shape_manual(values=c(20, 20, 20, 20))

#Changed appearance of plot (black and white theme) and x and y axis labels
p <- p + theme_classic() + xlab("Levels") + ylab("confident interval")



#To put levels on y axis you just need to use coord_flip()
p <- p+ coord_flip
```

```html
est          min          max            mean     origen
amount     -0.108911212 -0.100556517 -0.104733865 freshwater
exploration 0.191367902  0.20873976   0.200053831    freshwater
size     0.003166273  0.003276336     0.003221305    freshwater
source     -0.241657983 -0.225174165 -0.233416074   freshwater
amount     0.07         0.08          0.075       marine
exploration 0.33         0.34            0.335         marine
size     0.01         0.01          0.01         marine
source    -1.95          -1.9         -1.925         marine
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your code, there is `width=0` in `geom_errorbar` that is why you can not see error bars. In addition, you should write `coord_flip()`. With these modifications, your code should work :

```
ggplot(Dataset,aes(x=est,ymin=min, ymax=max, y=mean, shape=est)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=min, ymax=max), color="black") + 
  geom_point(aes(size=1)) +
  guides(size=FALSE,shape=FALSE) + scale_shape_manual(values=c(20, 20, 20, 20)) +
  theme_classic() + xlab("Levels") + ylab("confident interval") +
  coord_flip()
```

However, instead of `geom_errorbar`, you can use its rotated version `geom_errorbarh`. Thus, no need to invert axes and `est` variable can be directly indicated as y-axe.

```
ggplot(aes(mean, est, label = origen), data=Dataset) +
  geom_point() +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel() +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=min, xmax=max)) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  xlab("confident interval") +
  ylab("Levels")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your anwer. However when removing width = 0 what appears are vertical bars and not the bar referring to ymax and ymin that should appear horizontally (in the case of geom_errorbar). So the picture goes on without this error-bar